# Rails Active Record Associations for model which may map to different model types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm building an RoR application which has a `User` and `Product` classes. A user many have many photos as may a product, but each must also have a single `profile_picture`.

Users:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures
end
```

Products:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures
end
```

I'm struggling to define the `pictures` model which is currently:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
  has_one :product
end
```

The schema for pictures is as follows (timestamps omitted for brevity):

```
create_table "pictures", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "image_url"
end
```

finally I have a migration to add a link for the profile picture to users and products

```
class AddPicturesToUsersAndWalks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :profile_picture, :picture
    add_column :products, :profile_picture, :picture
  end
end
```

I've read through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html I don't understand how these relationships should be formed or where in the database the foreign keys should be stored.

I cannot view the schema for the user or products table (`rake db:migrate` does not complain when run) because the following error is returned in the schema file (I assume this is related to the `profile_picture` in both but im unsure how to procede:

```
# Could not dump table "users" because of following NoMethodError
#   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Please note im using ruby on rails 4 and a sqlite3 database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails documentation actually describes *almost precisely* what you should do.

[A polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  # `imageable` is just a name for you to reference and can by anything
  # It is not a class, a table or anything else
  # It affects only corresponding DB column names
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
  # read as: I am an `imageable`, I can have a picture as one
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end
```

In database this is accomplished by associating not only through `id`, but also through a model name: in corresponging columns `<model>_id` and `<model>_type`. As opposed to simpler associations where class name is known and only an `id` is needed.

```
class CreatePictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pictures do |t|
      t.string  :data
      t.integer :imageable_id
      t.string  :imageable_type
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way of linking the profile picture so i can access it with @user.profile_picture too?

Comment: @user3576112 Looks like `has_one :profile_picture, class_name: "Picture", as: :imageable`. Something similar.

Comment: thanks, would that be saved as a refernce in the user table or just a picture_id?

Comment: @user3576112 disregard, I'm wrong. The ownership is stored on the `belongs_to` side, and with that there's no way to distinguish simple pics from a profile one. I'm thinking...

Comment: @user3576112 the best option would be placing a pic directly **inside** the User model as a field. You don't want an extra query each time a User is required.

Comment: so create a migration with `add_column :users, :profile_picture, :picture` that adds a int column to the schema. that doesnt seem right to me

Comment: @user3576112 Yep, it isn't. Your `Picture` model includes an image itself through some mechanism, you could use it to attach an image to a `User` as well, not only a `Picture`. Unifying image attachments is not always great.