# Ruby on Rails named class property of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have two classes `Product` and `user` which have a `has_many` relationship with a polymorphic type as such.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I want to also add a new property to the user models of `profile_picture` so `@user.profile_picture` will return a picture object. how can this be achieved? In particular the migration to add the foreign key to users.

Edit: I've updated the user model as such

```
has_one :profile_picture, class_name: "Picture", foreign_key: "profile_picture_id"
```

and added the following migration

```
add_column :users, :profile_picture_id, :integer
```

however i dont appear to be able to set the profile picture if someone could explain what exactly i am doing wrong it would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: Ive reviewed that link, from which my current polymophic associations come. what i dont understand is how to add new a property to the user model which will be of type picture.

Comment: `has_one :picture, as: :profile_picture`

Comment: Hello again. You didn't follow my answer close enough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594975/rails-active-record-associations-for-model-which-may-map-to-different-model-type/25595055#25595055

Comment: sorry updated question to be clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no **direct** way to achieve this when using associations properly.

The data structure is wrong. You are trying to **associate one and the same model in two different ways**. And the problem is: **these two ways interfere with each other**.

You are effectively trying to store different types of objects using the same type. A direct way (suggested in another answer) would leave you with no way to determine which are simply `User`'s pictures and what is his `profile_picture` among them. So any possible solution would require adding a way to distinguish a `profile_picture`.

Just yesterday I wrote [an example on how to use "single table inheritance"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574745/i-need-help-properly-forming-this-activerecord-association/25584930#25584930). It actually fits well here, you need two similar data constructs to behave in different ways. To make it work, you will need two things:

1. Add STI support to `pictures` table:
   `rails g migration AddTypeToPictures type:string:index`
   ...and make sure you add a `type` column of type `string` with an index on it.
2. `rails g model ProfilePicture --no-migration --parent=Picture`
   This class will be created empty, but will inherit everything from `Picture`, so it should stay empty in many cases.

Then just a simple association should work on any class:

```
has_one :profile_picture, as: :imageable
```

Let's assume we added this to `User`. Then the search criteria to find a `User`'s profile picture will be:

- `type` is `"ProfilePicture"`
- `imageable_type` is `"User"`
- `imageable_id` is equal to `id` of the user in question

Searches have become cumbersome, right? Well, this should work, but I don't recommend all this, it has implications and alternatives:

- *Whatever database column you decide to add to `ProfilePicture`, it will have to be added to `Picture` even if it's not used: they are stored in the same table.*
  **Solution:** making `ProfilePicture` a full-fledged model: make a table for it, make it inherit `ActiveRecord::Base`.
- *Fetching a user's profile picture will require an extra database query with three (wow!) different criteria.*
  **Solution (recommended):** placing a profile picture inside a corresponding model the same way it's done for `Picture`: this will require no extra queries to fetch a profile picture at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures
  has_one :profile_picture, :class_name => "Picture"
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment: I wonder how that should work. To my knowledge - it shouldn't, there's no way to pick the exact `profile_picture` amongst all of the user's `Picture`s. There's no data for that.

Comment: mybe i misunderstood the question... its not very well written... :\
it should work if user have foreign key to picture

Comment: thanks i can see how adding a new has one property to the user class would work, how could that map to the user table in the database though. updated question to hopefully be clearer