# "has_two" model relationship with polymorphic model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations, has-one

I have a polymorphic PLACE model like this:

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :placeable, polymorphic: :true
...
```

So, for example, in my Lodging model I have something like:

```
class Lodging < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :place, as: :placeable, dependent: :destroy
...
```

And they work as expected.
The point is that now I want to create a CarRental model and this model has TWO places, on is the pick-up place and the other one is the drop-off place.

So I wrote:

```
class Transportation < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :start_place, as: :placeable, dependent: :destroy
has_one :end_place, as: :placeable, dependent: :destroy
```

And of course that does not work. Any insights on how to do that?

**EDIT 1: IF I DO LIKE**

```
class Transportation < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :start_place, class_name: 'Place', as: :placeable, dependent: :destroy
has_one :end_place, class_name: 'Place', as: :placeable, dependent: :destroy
```

It works! But why? Where is the start or end information saved?

** EDIT 2: NOPE, IT DOES NOT WORK **
It does not work... =(

Comment: ...it works, but are you sure that it works **correctly**? From what I see, it should return **the same start and end**. Since, as you stated, there's nowhere to store that information.

Comment: You are right. It does not work @D-side. My tests were errouneous...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, associations spitted out errors before because of the unknown classes. `has_one :start_place` by default assumes you mean a class `StartPlace` that doesn't exist. It singularizes the term (as best as it can) and converts it to `CamelCase`. Once you've specified that you mean `Place`, it's clear.

You should be adding a new column anyways.Let's try single table inheritance (STI). Add a column `type` of type `string` to your `places` table:

```
rails generate migration AddTypeToPlaces type:string
```

...make sure it does what it says, then migrate and create new models like so:

```
rails generate model StartPlace --no-migration --parent=Place
rails generate model EndPlace   --no-migration --parent=Place
```

**Note: they don't get a dedicated table and inherit from `Place`, not `ActiveRecord::Base`.** It should generate two empty classes, that's fine, they inherit things from `Place`.

...then revert your associations to what didn't work a while ago:

```
has_one :start_place, as: :placeable, dependent: :destroy
has_one :end_place,   as: :placeable, dependent: :destroy
```

...and they should work now, because `StartPlace` is defined as

> `Place` with `type` equal to `"StartPlace"`

...same with `EndPlace` with corresponding `type`.

I described this quite some time ago [for a similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25596445/2076787).

Comment: Hey @D-side, what should I do if I have the same Place as Start and End places?

Comment: @Guido then this structure fails =) You can make use `has_many :through` through, by applying the same thing to a join model (`StartLink`?) and leaving `Place` as it was before. It depends on your app logic, what's best.

Comment: Or you could have two objects and compare whether these are in the same place with a method.

Comment: Since I will keep Place as polymorphic, because Lodging, Activities and other things can have places (locations) I think I will also add has_one Place to Transportation model. If Start and End places are the same, I will save this one place. If not, I save them but I dont save it and create a class to compare. What do you think?

Comment: @Guido I don't know the logic of your app well enough to advise. Another resolution would be to keep a single `Place` and use multiple `belongs_to` with corresponging foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema doesn't make sense to me - that places belong to lodgings etc.  Surely there's a fixed number of places, and then they can have a number of different things in them?  In your schema the same place could be in the database lots of times which seems wrong. I don't think that polymorphic associations are the way to go here either.

I would model this like so:

```
class Place
  has_many :lodgings
  has_many :starting_transportations, :class_name => "Transportation", :as => :start_place
  has_many :ending_transportations, :class_name => "Transportation", :as => :end_place

class Lodging
  belongs_to :place #using lodgings.place_id

class Transportation
  belongs_to :start_place, :class_name => "Place" #via transportations.start_place_id
  belongs_to :end_place, :class_name => "Place" #via transportations.end_place_id
```

btw, i think "Location" is a better name than "Place" for physical locations in the real world.  "Place" sounds too vague.

Comment: Thank you @max-williams for your answer. You are right, the name Places is really not the best choice and I am thinking of changing it to locations, as you said. The point is I populate the Place with information I gather from Google Places API. So, a Trip has_many lodgings and car_rentals and they both have places. So you think the best solution would be to check if the place already exists and only create a new one if it does not? The point here is that I allow the user to edit any information they want from Place (such as street, photo, etc).

Comment: Can you take a look at my edited question? I made those changes and it worked....

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't have the same place twice in your database.  Think about this question.  "Given that i'm in place X, what lodgings are here?"

Comment: Thanks for the insights... I guess it looks comfusing because of the "Place" name I have been using (and will change) intead of Location. My model is pretty much an address, lat lng etc. So Every logding has a location (address)....